# Unwanted white space on the right and on the bottom of my site background in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap and I have this problem only when I'm on a mobile browser, when I resize my desktop browser the background resizes and works without any white extra white space.
I also have a navbar at the top that gets truncated by the mobile browser but not on desktop.

In the css I have `background-size: cover; background-position: center; html { height: 100%}`
I also tried adding width 100% to html but nothing changed.

I have no idea why this isn't behaving like it is on desktop. This is the site: https://cantuga.000webhostapp.com/udm/startup/startup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about the overflow.

```
 html,body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `width: 400px;` from below class

```
hr {
    width: 400px;
    border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: this also solved it and made the site look better, thank you!